# How to pass parameter to a referenced subroutine called from some other subroutine

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
sub test1 {
my $arg = shift;
print "$arg";
}
my $rs = \&test1;
sub test2 {
my $value = shift;
print "$value \n";
return $rs;
}



&test2("hello")->("Bye");
```

It is working fine as expected. But if in test1 sub we want to pass parameter from test2 sub. Something like

```
use strict;
use warnings;
sub test1 {
my $arg = shift;
print "$arg";
}
my $rs = \&test1;
sub test2 {
my $value = shift;
print "$value \n";
return $rs($value);
}

&test2("hello")->();
```

I know it is wrong syntax but dont know how to do that. I hope question is clear.

I want the output as 
    hello
    hello

Not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke Coderefs like `$coderef->(@args)`. E.g.

```
sub hello {
  my $name = shift;
  print "Hello $name\n";
}

sub invoke {
  my ($code, @args) = @_;
  $code->(@args);
}

invoke(\&hello, "World");
```

Output: `Hello World`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have a *reference* to a function, you dereference it like any other *reference* with the `->`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub test1 {
   my $arg = shift;
   print "$arg";
}

my $rs = \&test1;

sub test2 {
   my $value = shift;
   print "$value \n";
   return $rs->($value);  # <---
}

test2("hello");

# prints
hello
hello
```